# Can you get/change data of ALL instances of an object from within a shared function within a class?

Tags: vb.net

Problem:

I have a class where I have a eventlog that logs for that particular instance of the class and logs to a shared eventlog and to track changes across all instances.

My issue is that I want the logs to be re sizable in their number of entries and I need to make sure that the shared log is never smaller than any of the instanced logs. Is it possible to check this?

What I've tried:

I've seen a-lot about GetType and reflections and I've been able to get instance names but I can't figure out how to reference data within those instances.

Below is a psuedocode of where I am at.

```
Public Class Test
  Public InstancedLog As DataSet
  Public Shared SharedLog As DataSet

  Public Shared Sub ResizeSharedLog(ByRef DesiredSize As Integer)

    If DesiredSize < ("check and sum up the size of all instances of InstancedLog") Then
        'can't resize, too small.
    Else
        'resize to DesiredSize.
    End If

  End Sub
End Class
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `InstanceLog` will only be available on an instance of the class. If you call `ClassName.ResizeSharedLog` then you have no instance of the class to work on. If you passed in a List(of Test) as an argument of 'ResizeSharedLog` you could work on the InstanceLog of each item in the list.

Comment: Firstly, why are you declaring `DesiredSize` as `ByRef`?  Are you setting it to a different value inside the method?  That is the only reason to declare that parameter `ByRef`.  If that's not what you're doing, change it to `ByVal` and learn what `ByRef` actually does.

Comment: If you wanted to be able to affect each existing instance from a `Shared` method then you would also need a `Shared` field that referred to a collection of those instances.  You could define a constructor in your class that added the new instance to that collection.  In that case, you should probably implement the `IDisposable` interface and remove the current instance from the collection in the `Dispose` method too.  That's not perfect because an instance may get left behind for a while if someone writes bad code and fails to dispose it but it's pretty much as good as you'll get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of a class that tracks its own instances:

```
Public Class Class1
    Implements IDisposable

    Private Shared instances As New List(Of Class1)

    Public Sub New()
        instances.Add(Me)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub TouchEveryInstance()
        For Each instance As Class1 In instances
            'Use instance here.
        Next
    End Sub

#Region "IDisposable Support"
    Private disposedValue As Boolean ' To detect redundant calls

    ' IDisposable
    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If Not disposedValue Then
            If disposing Then
                ' TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
                instances.Remove(Me)
            End If

            ' TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override Finalize() below.
            ' TODO: set large fields to null.
        End If
        disposedValue = True
    End Sub

    ' TODO: override Finalize() only if Dispose(disposing As Boolean) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
    'Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    '    ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(disposing As Boolean) above.
    '    Dispose(False)
    '    MyBase.Finalize()
    'End Sub

    ' This code added by Visual Basic to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(disposing As Boolean) above.
        Dispose(True)
        ' TODO: uncomment the following line if Finalize() is overridden above.
        ' GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub
#End Region

End Class
```

Most of that code is auto-generated by VS when you add the `Implements IDisposable` line.  The entire region was added automatically except the line that refers to the `instances` field.  I added the `instances` field, the constructor and the `TouchEveryInstance` method.

Comment: Wow, this helped so much. I was able to implement what I needed and got it working. You are my personal hero for the day. Thank you.